# cannot execute python script as sudo from command line

Tags: scripting, sudo, python

I have a centos 7 VM and I need sudo permissions to run certain shell commands in a python script. I have a `#!/usr/bin/env python3.7` at the top of my script and running it as `sudo ./script.py` gives me a `/usr/bin/env: python3.7: No such file or directory` error. How do I run my code as sudo? Just to clarify, it does run if I simply enter `./script.py`, but I get a `permission denied` when the script tried to execute 3 specific commands hence the need for sudo.

`echo $PATH` result:

```
/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/sbin:/home/centos/.local/bin:/home/centos/bin:/home/centos/.local/bin:home/centos/bin
```

`sudo echo $PATH` gives the same result as above.

`type python3.7` gives me:
`python3.7 is /usr/local/bin/python3.7`

Comment: It appears your `PATH` includes `python3.7` whereas the `PATH` of `root` does not. Try `echo $PATH` and `sudo echo $PATH` to confirm, they should contain the output of `type python3.7`

Comment: I understand theoretically what you mean, I just have no idea how to fix it. I added to my post the results from those commands

Comment: @Panki isn't `$PATH` expanded by the shell before `sudo` is even run? (@BloodLord: `#!/bin/env /usr/local/bin/python3.7` should work for the moment, in particular if you're not worried about cross-distro compatibility, even if it's not the nicest solution.)

Comment: @UlrichSchwarz the script will only be run on centos 7 machines (im not sure if thats what you mean by cross-distro) so I think it should be fine

Comment: What is the output of `sudo sh -c 'echo $PATH'`? Also, @UlrichSchwarz probably meant `#!/usr/local/bin/python3.7` and not `#!/bin/env /usr/local/bin/python3.7`.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of problems with

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.7
```

The first is, that `python3.7` must be in the PATH of the user that runs the script. Apparently, for your root-user, this is not the case.

The second is, that it runs the first `python3.7` that is in the PATH. This may not be a big issue when you explicitly request version 3.7, but I've encountered a number of `#!/usr/bin/env python`-s that ran 3 instead of the required 2 etcetera.

That is why I do not recommend using `#!/usr/bin/env`.

There are 3 solutions to your problem:

- put `/usr/local/bin/` in the PATH of root (not recommended because of the `local`; that is the reason why it is not as default in the PATH)
- use `#!/usr/local/bin/python3.7` in your script. This will probably break if you use it on other systems where python is under `/usr/bin`
- use a default installation of python, where `python` is under `/usr/bin`; I would recomend to use only `#!/usr/bin/python3` and not the sub-version.

Comment: So my script requires a version of python3.7 of earlier. Will the 3rd option still work on other machines? Like will it make sure that python3.7 specifically is installed, or juste use whatever version of python3 the host has?

Comment: That means that on my installations (Mint Linux), your script breaks (Mint is 3.8). Unless you have very specific reasons why your script must not run on the latest Python, I would suggest making it less version dependent.  Otherwise, use the second option.